# Jackson deserialize JSON with extra properties using @JsonRootName

Tags: java, json-deserialization, jackson2

I want to deserialize an object which is annotated with `@JsonRootName`. However the JSON in which the object is transported contains another extra property. As a result Jackson is complaining with:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (FIELD_NAME), expected END_OBJECT: Current token not END_OBJECT (to match wrapper object with root name 'account'), but FIELD_NAME at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 26]`.

Apparently deserialization of `@JsonRootName` annotated objects works ONLY if that object is the sole property in JSON file - since it's not expecting the `"lastTransactionID"` to be there.

Here's my `Account` class:

```
@JsonRootName("account")
public class Account {
    private String id;
}
```

This is the JSON I need to deserialise:

```
{
  "account": {
    "id": "1234"
  },
  "lastTransactionID": "1"
}
```

Since I'm using spring I have this setup also `spring.jackson.deserialization.unwrap_root_value=true`.

Is there any way to solve this without:

- having to write a custom deserializer?

OR

- intercepting the response and stripping it of the extra property before deserialization takes place?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like simplest way to solve this issue is create wrapper for `Account` class and deserialise json as usual with disabled `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` feature.

```
public static class Wrapper {
    public Account account;
}
```

In this case other fields will be ignored.

It's not a nice solution, I know, but it solve a problem.

Comment: It's also the solution I want to avoid the most. I have a bunch of similar models, all of which are accompanied with `"lastTransactionId"` property.

Answer (score 0):

We can use ObjectMapper to Map json to java Objects.

```
public Account jsonToObject(Map<String, Object> map){
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Account account = objectMapper.convertvalue(map.get("account"),Account.class);
    return account;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is in fact a custom deserializer (which btw I ended up using) but in my question I explicitly stated: _Is there any way to solve this without having to write a custom deserializer?_

Answer (score -1):

You can use **JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)** annotation on your Account class. Please refer below link for more details.
https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/10/entity-object-conversion-to-dto-object.html